# PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type - when using an array as a var in oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I get 'expression is of wrong type' error when I'm trying to execute the following sql procedure:

```
DECLARE
  v_date TIMESTAMP(6) := to_date('03-11-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
BEGIN
  for newiD in (select tabA.id from tabA where tabA.prop = 1)
  loop
    insert into tabB values (newId, 'testval', 'testval', newId, v_date);
  end loop;
END;
```

Is there another way I can declare the array I'm trying to store into the **newId** variable?

**Update**: The data type of the tabA.id and the next tabB.newId is the same - NUMBER(19,0)

Comment: I checked the data type and is the same for both coluims, sorry, I can't post the entire table structures..

Comment: I suppose that newId is a record, to get id value use newId.id in your insert clause

Comment: Yes.. that was the problem, is working now with newId.id. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Welcome, I posted answer below

Comment: As an aside, if you declare a variable of type `timestamp`, why do you assign a value to it using `to_date`? This will force Oracle to perform an implicit conversion from `date` to `timestamp`. Use `to_timestamp` instead, with the same arguments.

Answer (score 3):

A better way, with no loops and just SQL, could be:

```
DECLARE
  v_date TIMESTAMP(6) := to_date('03-11-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy');
BEGIN
    insert into tabB    /* here it would be better to list the columns */
      select tabA.id, 'testval', 'testval', tabA.id, v_date
      from tabA
      where tabA.prop = 1
END;
```

Comment: Yes, rigth. Here is no extra switching between sql and plsql

Answer (score 2):

In this case newId is a record wich has one field: id. That's why you need to put newId.id in your insert clause.